# Displaylink USB 3.0 does not work on boot

Tags: usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, displaylink

So I think I have narrowed it down, the computer doesn't seem to register the USB ports during start up. With my monitor plugged into the HDMI port on the video card and keyboard plugged into the USB i can't make selections on the initial ubuntu boot page. however once that page passes if i am using one screen in the HDMI on the video card or have two black screens plugged into the Displaylink I can enter the root password and once I enter that it brings up the main login screen.

---

total n00b here so any assistance would be great. I installed ubuntu 19.10 on my first PC build last night, I was able to get the display link set up with no problem, however when I came home and started my computer up both screens stayed blank when I booted up. Keyboard and mouse lit up but the only way I could get logged into the computer was to hard shutdown plug one of the monitors hdmi into the video card and boot back up. Then only once I was all the way logged in my used account was able to switch the hdmi back into the display port and have both screens running.

Motherboard ASRock B450 
Video: Geforce GT 710 2GB DDRS
OS Ubuntu 19.10

Comment: Please click [edit]. Then provide the make and model of the PC and the video card. Get the model# from the serial sticker. If it is a home built/white box clone PC, please provide the make and model of the motherboard. Also please advise which Ubuntu release you are using, or if you are not using Ubuntu, which version you are using. Please don't use Add Comment for hi has no formatting ability; instead, please use [edit].

Comment: Since you mention this is a new build, Ubuntu 19.04 is the 2019-April (thus 19.04) release of Ubuntu and reaches EOL in a few weeks, so I'd suggest using starting again with 19.10 now instead of three weeks time when you'll need to upgrade  (18 January 2020 isn't far into the future).

Comment: @guiverc sorry, I am on 19.10.